# $A=90^\circ$ creating a problem in the $\tan(A\pm B)$ formulas

Tags: trigonometry

As the title suggests I am having problem using $\tan(90^\circ)$ in identities of $\tan(A+B),\tan(A-B)$. We can easily see that we get $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Suppose I don't know value of $\tan(150^\circ)$. So one option is just $\tan(90^\circ+60^\circ)$ but that doesn't yield any answer.

Can anyone explain how to do calculations for $\tan(150^\circ),$ using $\tan(A+B)$?

Comment: Hint: $\tan(x^\circ) = \tan(x^\circ + 180^\circ)$ and $\tan(-x^\circ) = -\tan(x^\circ)$

Comment: No i specifically want to use that formula

Comment: But still thanks

Comment: You can use $A=60^\circ$ and $B=60^\circ$ to get $\tan 120^\circ$. Then use $A=120^\circ$ and $B = 30^\circ$ to get $\tan 150^\circ$.

Comment: Undefined things do tend to make work difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want this $$tan150=\frac{tan90+tan60}{1-tan90tan60} $$Divide by $tan90$ $$\frac{1+\frac{tan60}{tan90}}{\frac{1}{tan90}-tan60} $$ Now $\frac{1}{tan90}=cot90=0$
Hence you get $tan150=\frac{-1}{\sqrt3}$

Comment: Ya thanks thats the trick then

Answer (score 1):

You can use $tan(180-30)$
Hence $tan150$ $$\frac{0-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}}{1+\frac{0}{\sqrt3}} $$

Comment: I have mentioned in the body i specifically want that firmula but thanks